# ¿Cómo implementar la función click de jquery en react?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Estoy estudiando react así que estoy intentando juntarlo con lo que ya sé de jquery, para tratar de armar un ecommerce, pero hay algo que va, pero no va en el código... Sucede que editando el código funciona, pero si le doy recargar a la página no toma la función y deja de funcionar, y si borro una letra o algo y vuelvo a guardar vuelve a funcionar, hasta que le doy a recargar al localhost y vuelve a dejar de funcionar.

La idea es que tengo una tienda con varios productos, le asigno una categoría dinámicamente y al seleccionar un enlace con la categoría me muestre solos los elementos con dicha categoría.

Los productos también son generados dinámicamente y se le asigna dinámicamente una categoría... Acá no lo muestra pero (click) en el editor aparece tachado. Creo que el problema va por ahí.

```
import $ from "jquery"
const MenuProductos = () => {
    $(".dropdown-menu .dropdown-item").click(function () {
        let catProducto = $(this).attr("categoria")
        $(".card").hide();
        $('.card[categoria="'+catProducto+'"]').show();
    })
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
              <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" categoria="all" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Categorias</a>
              <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li><a className="dropdown-item" categoria="perlas">perla</a></li>
                <li><a className="dropdown-item" categoria="piedras">piedras</a></li>
                <li><a className="dropdown-item" categoria="dijes">dijes</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default MenuProductos
```

Comment: Mira esta explicación, está muy buena
https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/react/react-jquery/#puedes-usar-jquery-en-react

Comment: "En el editor aparece tachado": ¿colocaste el mouse sobre _click_ para ver qué mensaje te da? Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.